# Round up time difference in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm able to get the time difference between two dates but i'm not able to round up the result it comes up like this `2.163611111111111`

```
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year =  currentDate.getFullYear()
var hour =  currentDate.getHours();
var minute= currentDate.getMinutes(); 
var second= currentDate.getSeconds(); 

var today = day + "/" + month + "/" + year 
var time =  hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second 
console.log(today+' '+time);
var date1 = new Date('12/7/2017 01:51:14');
var date2 = new Date(today+' '+time);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var hours = Math.abs(date2 - date1) / 36e5;
alert(hours)
```

this there i way i can round it up to get something like this `2.6`

Comment: try `Math.round()` instead of `Math.abs()`

Comment: try with `hours.toFixed(1)`

Comment: Agree with @prasad you may used toFixed(2)  your hours

Comment: Use can use var hoursRounded =  Math.round(hours * 10) / 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year =  currentDate.getFullYear()
var hour =  currentDate.getHours();
var minute= currentDate.getMinutes(); 
var second= currentDate.getSeconds(); 

var today = day + "/" + month + "/" + year 
var time =  hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second 
console.log(today+' '+time);
var date1 = new Date('12/7/2017 01:51:14');
var date2 = new Date(today+' '+time);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var hours = Math.abs(date2 - date1) / 36e5;
alert(parseFloat(hours.toFixed(2)));
```

Comment: .toFixed(), returnts a string. If you need number, you need to parseFloat it again.So may be something like this parseFloat(hours.toFixed(2))